# Set inet_interfaces for each postfix service

Tags: postfix, ipv6, ipv4, email-server

I have a complex postfix setup with dovecot authentication, amavis and spamassassin.

The inet_interfaces are set to my IPv4 address, IPv6 address and IPv4 and IPv6 loopback. But I want that the submission service only listen on the public IP addresses and not on localhost addresses. How can it set this?

Using `-o inet_interfaces= public ipv4, public ipv6` in master.cf does not work.

Comment: Have you tried recreating the submission port, but instead of calling it submission, call it `a.valid.ip.addr:587` ? Obviously, with an actual IP there :)

Comment: Did you restart the services? What are the logs telling?

Comment: Now I use "hostname:submission" and in /etc/hosts this name resolvs to my public ipv4 and ipv6 address. Now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad you got it going! :)

Answer (score 3):

I found out the solution.

First you have to check that in `/etc/hosts` file, your hostname is mapped to your IPv4 and IPv6 address.

Then you can can use this in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
...
yourhostname:submission   inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
...
```